# How to push notification to specific users in Xamarin.Forms Android?

Tags: android, push-notification, xamarin.forms

I have Implemented push notification in xamarin.forms android using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm) but it sends the notification to all the device.I want to send notification to the specific users only.How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

We use tags for this. Each user has a user Id and so when the device registers with azure, you add their user Id as a tag to the registration.

```
protected override void OnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId) {

    ...

    var tags = new List<string>() { "userId4" }; // Your UserId here

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.I will try this approach and let you know whether it fullfil my requirement or not.