# Push Notification to specific devices on xamarin forms android/ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, azure-notificationhub

I have successfully set up push notification using firebase and linked it up Azure notification hub using this guide from the Microsoft docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm

However I am now trying to push notification to specific devices using tags. There isn't currently a xamarin c# document. I have done some research around the area and found people solving what seems to be the same problem using dependency injection (which feels a little complex?). I have also found these two questions/answers:

[How to push notification to specific users in Xamarin.Forms Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506271/how-to-push-notification-to-specific-users-in-xamarin-forms-android)

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85935/how-to-push-notification-to-specific-users-in-xamarin-forms-android

Both of which point to the method "OnRegistered" which i don't seem to have? i've had another look through the documentation I followed to set up notifications in the first place and I seem to have followed it correctly?

I have the following code for android:

```cs
private void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
{
    // Register with Notification Hubs
    hub = new NotificationHub(ApplicationConstants.NotificationHubName,
        ApplicationConstants.ListenConnectionString, this);

    var tags = new List<string>() { };
    var regID = hub.Register(token, tags.ToArray()).RegistrationId;
}
```

I can obviously set the tags manually there, however how do i 'call' this Method again if the tags need to be changed?

So bottom line, my question is how do i set up push notification to specific devices on xamarin.forms android/ios?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like people are creating the xml using string class.

Comment: do you have a link to an example? @jdweng

Comment: string xml = "<receiver android:name=\"com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver\" android:exported=\"false\" />";

Comment: I might be getting confused, and excuse my ignorance but how would that help? At the moment i can send iOS/android notifications separate to each other. I want to be able to register phones to a group, say company A and company B. Then when i send notifications to company A, company B don't see them and visa versa if that makes sense? Sorry if i'm being unclear/ not understanding what your trying to say, Thanks.

Comment: I was answering question : "if the tags need to be changed?"

Comment: oh okay, sorry didn't quite make the link! what exactly would I do with the xml? This notification hub is all very new to me.

Comment: Look at step 6 on this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-gcm-android-push-to-user-google-notification